# Android 7.1 application with high RAM consumption

Tags: android, heap-memory, ram

I'm developing an android application intended to run on a device with Android 7.1 and 4GB of RAM memory. The algorithm needs approximately 1.5GB of RAM for it's correct behavior. Is there a way how to increase the RAM allowance for the application in order to make it work? Currently I'm getting out of memory exceptions.

Comment: You could try either [largeHeap](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) attribute or using JNI to allocate this memory.